# How to generate probability 3D plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, trng

I have already build my true random number generator and I want to visualised the results. I am testing a lot of generators, each of then will generate a txt.file. It is like

`543
35
68
3
...`

in the txt files. I want to draw a 3D plot in matlab. It should have 3 axes which are **Probability of each number, Generators and Interval of random numbers** See figure.
Those generators are 16 bits, so the biggist number is 65535. For example 30000 has been generated 10 times and this file has 100000 random numbers, so the probability of 30000 is 10/100000. Any help is appreciated !
[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj1Oz.png)

Comment: look at 'histogram2'

Answer (score 0):

You can use surfplot in MATLAB.

More info: [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html)